# How to display information taken from text area in netbeans (for a GUI)?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, textarea, jframe

I have taken information from a text area (on a JFrame) and saved it as a variable, but now I  would like to display the string thats stored in that variable in a different JFrame (which  already have created). how do i go about doing this?

Example:

1. one frame says: enter your name (store this value in a variable)
2. click proceed
3. closes first frame
4. second frame is open now and I want to display the name of the player (variable) in the top corner of the JFrame.

Any ideas on what to use from the swing palette?

Answer (score 0):

Save the value in a static variable so that you can use it anywhere.